# OpenNI. Error loading oni file (Bad File Extension)

Tags: linux, openni, ros

I am trying to use OpenNI and Nite from ROS framework.
Everything compiles without problems, but in execution, the first task I want to do is load an existing oni file to reproduce its content.
After having a look at the working code, I have this piece of code that appears everywhere:

```
ROS_INFO("Init OpenNi for Point Gesture");
nRetVal=g_context.Init();
nRetVal = g_context.OpenFileRecording("//home//alberto//desktop//recording.oni", g_player);
if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
{
      printf("Can't open recording %s\n", xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));
      return;
}
```

The file exists, the path is OK, I have tested it many times, but I always obtain the same error:
"Can't open recording Bad file extension"

Could it be because the Oni file has been created with a higher version of Open NI?
Mine is 1.5.4.0 in Ubuntu 12.04, and the file appears to have been created with 1.5.7.10....however, I do not have this version available.

How could I read and open this Oni file without errors? I can not continue with the rest of the application.

Thank you all very much in advance,

Comment: I tried once to create one with openni2 and read it with openni1 and it gave me a similar error. Make sure, you can read it with your current openni first... go to the samples in the folder you use when installing openni and open the niviewer with the file name as argument, if it opens then the error is not the version

Comment: Tested with the OpenNi viewer of the same version... same error. Bad File extension.so, I really do not have a clue of what is happening...

Comment: That is weird, do you another one to compare with? I think I can supply one done with 1.5.7 that opens perfectly with openni viewer and if it gives the same error it can be a version problem :S

Comment: That would be great...I have the 1.5.7.10 version of openNi compiled and ready for testing. If it works, I can change the packages from synaptic and use this compiled OpenNi instead

Comment: I am not right now in my office, but I will supply a link as soon as possible.